# Why does regedit.exe have HKCU permission for importing but reg.exe does not?

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-registry, regedit

I have a `.reg` file with current user values. If I use `reg.exe` in a bat file to import it says:

> ERROR: Error accessing the registry.

If I use `regedit.exe` there are no issues. For regedit.exe I use:

```
regedit filename
```

For `reg.exe` I use:

```
reg import filename
```

For `regedit` I do not use the `/s` switch so I can see whether successful and it has no issues because it is the HKCU hive. It asks if I want to, I click `yes`, then it says successful.

`reg.exe` is not supposed to have issues with the HKCU hive but for me will not import anything into HKCU. Why is that? If `regedit.exe` works and does the import one would think `reg.exe` should work, too.

I would use `regedit.exe` with the `/s` switch but that does not give a report if it fails. `regedit.exe` is a graphical program and `reg.exe` is console. With `reg.exe` I can follow with `ERRORLEVEL` in the bat file.

If I edit the bat file with:

```
reg add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\.... /f /v valuename /t REG_DWORD /d "1"
```

it works fine. The problem is I cannot import a `.reg` file.

Comment: Regedit is the proper Microsoft tool to use. Not any other replacement.

Comment: @john, not true. reg.exe is a standard windows program.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/reg     ......   Yes, but it is just as dangerous as regedit.

Comment: None of the apps is "dangerous". User actions can be dangerous, but then so are also e.g. many hurtful things they can do by just using a device like laptop. There's 0 reason for warning users about registry edit apps on such a website.

Comment: I understand your point, but this place is littered with damaged machines caused by careless or inexperienced use of registry Apps.

Comment: and you run as admin, elevated command prompt and all that?

Comment: @Joep, no. Yes it does work if I run elevated, but the HKCU hive is then for the administrator user and not my user. Also I should not have to run elevated which is why I asked this question.